# Improving paclet formatting

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, customization, paclets

Cross posted on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1266698)

---

For such an increasingly relevant data type the `Paclet` has a particularly useless formatted form.

Can we do better?

In particular we'll want the `Paclet` [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to be attractive, show particularly relevant paclet info, and be customizable.

Here's my version, to get people started:

```
pacletKeyOrdering =
  {
   "Name", "Version", "Creator",
   "Description", "Root", "WolframVersion",
   "MathematicaVersion", "Internal", "Loading",
   "Qualifier", "SystemID", "BuildNumber",
   "Tags", "Icon", "Categories",
   "Authors", "Extensions"
   };
With[{keyOrdering = pacletKeyOrdering},
  pacletInfoAssociation[PacletManager`Paclet[k__]] := 
   KeySortBy[First@FirstPosition[keyOrdering, #] &]@
    With[
     {
      base =
       KeyMap[Replace[s_Symbol :> SymbolName[s]], <|k|>]
      },
     ReplacePart[base,
      "Extensions" ->
       AssociationThread[
        First /@ Lookup[base, "Extensions", {}],
        Association@*Rest /@ Lookup[base, "Extensions", {}]
        ]
      ]
     ]
  ];
If[! AssociationQ@$pacletIconCache, $pacletIconCache = <||>];
pacletGetIcon[a_Association] :=
  Replace[
   FileNames[
    Lookup[
     a,
     "Icon",
     "PacletIcon.m" | "PacletIcon.png"
     ],
    a["Location"]
    ],
   {
    {f_, ___} :>

     Lookup[$pacletIconCache, f, $pacletIconCache[f] = Import[f]],
    {} :>

     With[{f = 
        "https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/raw/master/\
Resources/Icons/PacletIcon.png"
       },
      Image[
       Lookup[$pacletIconCache, f, $pacletIconCache[f] = Import[f]],
       ImageSize -> 28
       ]
      ]
    }
   ];
$formatPaclets = True;
Format[p_PacletManager`Paclet /;
    ($formatPaclets && AssociationQ@
       pacletInfoAssociation[p])] :=

  With[{a = pacletInfoAssociation[p]},
   RawBoxes@
    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
     "Paclet",
     p,
     pacletGetIcon[a],
     KeyValueMap[
      BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[
        {Row[{#, ": "}], #2},
        StandardForm
        ] &,
      a[[{"Name", "Version"}]]
      ],
     Join[
      {
       If[KeyMemberQ[a, "Location"],
        BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[
         {Row[{"Location", ": "}],
          With[{l = a["Location"]},
           Button[
            Hyperlink[l],
            SystemOpen[l],
            Appearance -> None,
            BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink"
            ]
           ]},
         StandardForm
         ],
        Nothing
        ]
       },
      KeyValueMap[
       BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[
         {Row[{#, ": "}], #2},
         StandardForm
         ] &,
       KeyDrop[a, {"Name", "Version", "Location"}]
       ]
      ],
     StandardForm
     ]
   ];
FormatValues[PacletManager`Paclet] =
  SortBy[
   FormatValues[PacletManager`Paclet],
   FreeQ[HoldPattern[$formatPaclets]]
   ];
```

This is what I use in my own packages. It makes paclets that look like this:

```
PacletFind /@ {"BTools", "ChemTools"} // Flatten
```

[image: img]

(*sorry about bad raster quality*)

Of course where this is actually useful is that it shows you what's inside the paclet:

```
PacletFind["MQTTLink"][[1]]
```

[image: asdasd]

Comment: Why don't you use the icon set in `PacletInfo.m` that's also displayed in the documentation?

Comment: @Szabolcs I honestly didn’t know that existed (haven’t read the `”PacletInfo.m"` question enough). I’ve now swapped things in the package where this is implemented to use that by default.

Answer (score 11):

### Demonstration

Here's what the end result looks like with my implementation:

[image]

I included information that I personally find important and useful.  Of course, this is a bit subjective, and there's a tradeoff between conciseness/skimmability and completeness.

If the paclet has a standard icon that would be shown in the documentation centre, it will be used for formatting. Otherwise, a default icon is used (a rectangle here).

If the paclet has documentation, its name will be a clickable hyperlink (notice MaTeX in blue).  This is currently determined based on the paclet name, not the documentation content that the paclet itself includes.  In principle, the documentation for a loadable package may be contained within a different paclet than the package itself.  Even in this case, it will be the package paclet whose name is clickable.

A few more examples (notice documentation link):

[image]

---

### Implementation

The implementation below is commented so people can understand and modify it easily.  It aims to be compatible with 10.0+.

In general, `` PacletManager` `` may not be in the context path (this happens when the context is local to the notebook). Thus, we start with

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
```

If I were not lazy, I would just type out the context manually where needed.

First we remove the existing `MakeBoxes` definitions for `Paclet`:

```
FormatValues[Paclet] = DeleteCases[FormatValues[Paclet], HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][MakeBoxes[___]]] :> ___];
```

Here's a default icon at a reasonable size. Normally one would design a better one.

```
$defaultPacletIcon = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 23];
```

If the paclet comes with an icon, we use it. Otherwise, we use the default.

```
getPacletIcon[p_Paclet] :=     
 With[{file = FileNameJoin[{p["Location"], p["Thumbnail"]}]},
  If[FileType[file] === File,
   Show[Import[file], ImageSize -> 23], (* standard icon size is 46x46, resizing to 23 gives us a crisp result *)
   $defaultPacletIcon
  ]
 ]
```

This is a helper function to conditionally include information which may or may not be available. The value is optionally post-processed with `fun` (4th argument).

```
optionalItem[p_Paclet, name_, selector_, fun_: Identity] := 
 With[{value = p[selector]},
  If[value =!= "",
   BoxForm`SummaryItem[{name, fun[value]}],
   Unevaluated@Sequence[]
  ]
 ]
```

Now follows the main formatter. Note that if `p` is a `Paclet` expression, properties can be extracted using `p["selector"]`.  This method is more robust than parsing the `Paclet` expression and much more robust than parsing the PacletInfo file directly. For example, `"MathematicaVersion"` will extract the compatibility version regardless of how it was specified in the PacletInfo file (`MathematicaVersion`, `WolframVersion`, `"WolframVersion"`, etc.)

```
Paclet /: MakeBoxes[p_Paclet, form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] :=     
 BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
  Paclet, (* head *)
  p, (* expression *)
  getPacletIcon[p], (* icon *)
  { (* always visible items *)
   With[{name = p["Name"]},
    BoxForm`SummaryItem[{
      "Name: ", 
      If[Documentation`ResolveLink["paclet:" <> name] =!= Null, (* simple way to check for working documentation *)
        Hyperlink[name, "paclet:" <> name], 
        name
      ]
    }]
   ],
   BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Version: ", p["Version"]}]
  },
  { (* expandable items *)
   optionalItem[p, "Description: ", "Description"],
   optionalItem[p, "Creator: ", "Creator"],
   optionalItem[p, "URL: ", "URL", Hyperlink],
   optionalItem[p, "Compatibility: ", "MathematicaVersion"],
   optionalItem[p, "Extensions: ", "Extensions", #[[All, 1]] &]
   },
  form
 ]
```

Comment: Hm ... the documentation detection is not working great.  Consider e.g. `PacletFind["ServiceConnection_MailChimp"]`.  There's some room for improvement here, but I won't have time for that now.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think to do a documentation link. That's good extension. You can also always test ``Documentation`ResolveLink["paclet:" <> StringReplace[ name, "ServiceConnection_ "->"ref/service"]]`` to handle service connection links.